# Taylor expansion of the integral of a function

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

[Help me with this problem please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAiad.png)

$\arctan(x)$ can be expressed as $\displaystyle \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-x)^{n-1}}{2n-1} = x-x^3/3+x^5/5-x^7/7 + \ldots$
But not sure how to proceed with the Taylor expansion. There is some extension to this problem too. Please help me how to proceed.

Comment: you need to drop factorials. with factorials you get $\sin x$ and not $\arctan x$.

Comment: oh yeah! thank you for the edit

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

The Taylor series for $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ is

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

Now, integrate the series term by term.

---

To evaluate the series written in the link, combine the series for $\arctan(x)$ with the series for $\log (1+x)$ and let $x=1$.

Comment: :-) Looks good.  Maybe want to add the expansion of $\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: Yeah, convincing... Well, I got the hint for series expansion... :) Thank you @Dr. MV

Answer (score 2):

We can start with $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-\cdots$ and integrate to obtain the taylor series , $\displaystyle \arctan x = \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-x)^{n+1}}{2n+1}$

Another way is to see $\displaystyle \arctan(x) = \frac{1}{2i}\left(\ln(1+ix)-\ln(1-ix)\right)$ and use the taylor expansion of $\displaystyle\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-x)^{n-1}}{n}$

Comment: :-/ The $\arctan$ and $\ln$ complex relationship may be a bit confusing, but other than that this is a good answer.

Comment: That's the way how gregory derived $\theta$ in terms of $\tan \theta$ ;)

Comment: the relationship between ln and arctan is not confusing, but I got messed up at arctanx expressed as a summation @AdityaNarayanSharma